# google map places autocomplete not working properly, on blockUI

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

google map places `autocomplete` not working properly. it works on press enter but not working on mouse down. I mean location does not change on `mousedown`. It is working properly in outside of popup. you can check top link in `jsFiddle`.

[jsFiddle URL](http://jsfiddle.net/aXXg3/)